# CPU at 100% while the CPU miner is off

Tags: cpu-mining, gpu-mining, mining-hardware, windows

My CPU is being maxed at 100% due to system interupts. I am not using the CPU to mine as it is a celeron(newest model). I am running 6 GPUs barely, there seems to be a bottle neck im thinking due to the CPU . Has anyone come across this before or know why this is happening. I am running Windows 10 Pro, and have re-installed it twice with all appropriate drivers for the CPU and GPUs. The L3 cashe is 2mb should i get a new one with 3mb?? Any help would be great!